# parallel execution using POM(pagefactory) reupdate

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

I wasn't able to find a solution to this so i post here for assistance. I have problems running the tests in parallel(using POM with page factory).

*\ Testbase class */

```
  public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters("Browsername")
        public void initializeaccount(String Browsername) 
        {
           if(Browsername.equals("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
                 driver = new ChromeDriver();   
            }
              else if(Browsername.equals("chrome1")) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
                     driver = new ChromeDriver();   
                }
                  driver.manage().window().maximize();
                  driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
                  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(testutility.page_Load_Timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(testutility.page_Load_Timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                  driver.get(prop.getProperty("accounturl"));   
        }
```

* POM class *

```
public CreateAccountPage()  {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    //action 
    public String vailidatewebpagetitle() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return driver.getTitle();
    }
```

* Test case *

```
    public Accountpagetest() {
    super(); 
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setup()
{
    
    CreateAccountPage = new CreateAccountPage();    
}
@Test(priority=1)
public void verifycreateaccountwebpagetitle() throws InterruptedException
{
    String title = CreateAccountPage.vailidatewebpagetitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(title, "google");
}
```

* XML file *

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel= "tests" thread-count="2">   
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="Report.DownloadReport" />
    </listeners>
 <test name="Testchrome" parallel= "methods" thread-count="5">
 <parameter name="Browsername" value ="chrome"> </parameter>
    <classes>
   <class name="testcases.Accountpagetest"/> 
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
<test name="Testchrome2" parallel= "methods" thread-count="5">
 <parameter name="Browsername" value ="chrome1"> </parameter>
    <classes>
   <class name="testcases.Accountpagetest"/> 
</classes>
 </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I am getting java nullpointerexception error

```
  ===============================================
TestSuite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 0, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pages.CreateAccountPage.vailidatewebpagetitle(CreateAccountPage.java:44)
    at testcases.Accountpagetest.verifycreateaccountwebpagetitle(Accountpagetest.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pages.CreateAccountPage.vailidatewebpagetitle(CreateAccountPage.java:44)
    at testcases.Accountpagetest.verifycreateaccountwebpagetitle(Accountpagetest.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

** update
the error i am hitting, the /* POM class *\ createnewpage method driver is returning a null argument.

in any case, what i trying here is to run two chrome browsers for parallel testing.

Anyone have experience this problem before can kindly advise what corrections needs to be done? i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Read the parameter "Browsername" into method argument and remove the call to read the property inside the method code

```
public WebDriver driver;

@Parameters("Browsername")
    public void initializeaccount(String Browsername) 
    {
        
       if(Browsername.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
             driver = new ChromeDriver();   
        }
          else if(Browsername.equals("chrome1")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
                 driver = new ChromeDriver();   
            }
              driver.manage().window().maximize();
              driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
              driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(testutility.page_Load_Timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(testutility.page_Load_Timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
              driver.get(prop.getProperty("accounturl"));   
    }
```

Comment: i have reedited my post by updating \* test case */ and the \* new error message */, testngexception. kindly ignore the comments earlier and i have removed it.

Comment: reupdate, i'm have added @beforeclass annotation in testbase class.